# Не отображается элемент :before при загрузке на хостинг

Tags: html, css, псевдоэлемент

```
        При локальной работе с файлами все отображается корректно, но стоит только загрузить на хостинг, и все ломается, а именно, пропадает элемент :before
```

Локально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот при уже непосредственно на сайте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее код в html

```
<div id="partners" class="partners">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="partners__content">
                    <h2 class="partners__title caption-title">Партнеры</h2>
                    <div class="partners__logo">
                        <div class="partners__flex1">
                            <div class="partners__img">
                                <img src="img/partners-logo/ytong-logo1.png" alt="">
              <div class="partners__promt-1">
                <h4 class="caption">YTONG</h4>
                <p>Газобетонный блок YTONG производится из натуральных компонентов и во всем мире признаны экологическим чистым, нетоксичным строительным материалом.</p>
              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="partners__img">
                                <img src="img/partners-logo/bonolit.png" alt="">
              <div class="partners__promt-1">
                <h4 class="caption">Bonolit</h4>
                <p>Bonolit крупнейший завод по выпуску современного, экологичного и качественного стенового материала для строительства малоэтажного и многоэтажного жилья.</p>
              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="partners__img">
                                <img src="img/partners-logo/logotype-head.png" alt="">
              <div class="partners__promt-1">
                <h4 class="caption">Пластблок</h4>
                <p>Лучший производитель строительных материалов из полистиролбетона в России. Изделия, производимые заводом Пластблок, обладают уникальными характеристиками: энергоэффективность, прочность и долговечность.</p>
              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
          <div class="partners__flex2">
                            <div class="partners__img">
                                <img src="img/partners-logo/wienerberger.png" alt="">
              <div class="partners__promt-1">
                <h4 class="caption">Wienerberger</h4>
                <p>Крупноформатные керамические блоки Porotherm производятся австрийским концерном Wienerberger. Это теплые и очень прочные изделия с повышенным сопротивлением к сжатию и устойчивостью к воздействию высоких температур. Они не боятся морозов и перепадов температур, не содержат вредных веществ и токсичных добавок.</p>
              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="partners__img">
              <img src="img/partners-logo/gzhelsky-factory.png" alt="">
              <div class="partners__promt-1">
                <h4 class="caption">Гжельский кирпичный завод</h4>
                <p>Гжель предлагает широкий ассортимент кирпичей разных размеров и цветов. Вы можете использовать этот строительный материал как для возведения стен, так и для облицовки. В качестве используется экологически чистая глина из Гжельского месторождения, которая обла-дает уникальными физическими свойствами.</p>
              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

И css

```
  .partners__img {
position: relative;}
.partners__promt-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -90px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 210px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 22px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 24px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0px 24px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 24px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  text-align:initial;
  z-index: 2; }
.partners__promt-1:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; }
.partners__promt-1 h4 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 8px; }
.partners__promt-1 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px; }
.partners__promt-1:hover {
  opacity: 1; }
.partners__flex2 .partners__img .partners__promt-1 {
  bottom: -190px;
}
```

Comment: Вы не забыли почистить кэш браузера, чтобы CSS обновился?

Comment: Да, попробуйте обновить страницу "ctrl+f5"

Comment: Помогло, спасисбо!)